# How can I display log message in scrollable text-viewer in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, logging

I want to display Xcode console log after build an app scrollable text viewer (in app).

How can I display Xcode console log message to an app?

[image]
already I was created scrollable text-viewer but I've no idea how can setting up AppDelegate and print running script log in app

[image]

my script are based on terminal shell command.

I would like to print shell command script are display in a scrollable text-viewer.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow!  
I am not sure what you want to achieve, but it seems to me that you want to display the Xcode debugger logs that you see in the debug area a the bottom of the Xcode display in an app view.  
This is simply not possible, at least at real time, since when you run the app, it is not attached to the debugger.  
Or what is your intension?

Comment: my purpose are display a running message into a text viewer box  such a xcod console log

Comment: Do you mean **any** running text, and the Xcode console log is just an example?

Comment: such a like this~

1   HWAEnabler                          0x00000001000022b7 -[GUIHandler ProgressInc] + 140
2   Foundation                          0x00007fff3915c87e __NSThread__start__ + 1194
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001003c1dc3 _pthread_body + 126
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001003c4e8d _pthread_start + 66
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001003c0e11 thread_start + 13

this dump log are from Xcode console at bottom of right.

Comment: I am sorry, I still don't understand your problem: Is the problem 1) to display any text in a scrollable view or 2) to display a stack trace at a certain point during the execution of your app, as Xcode does when it stops say at a breakpoint? A solution to case 1) is simple: Just look up e.g. [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/560-uiscrollview-tutorial-getting-started). And in case 2: Why is Xcode not enough?